# Display Customer Activity Notes on Sales Order After CustomerID entered

Tags: acumatica

I have a request from a pop up of the Customers Activity Notes after the Customer ID has been entered on a sales order. Currently they have set up specific instructions for entering an order for customer (could be different for each customer). We have entered them under the customers Activity Notes with a specific ID in the subject field. The notes will be in the body of the activity.

Rather then copy this info to the Sales Order Activity Notes, they would just like to display the Activity Notes from the Customers Activity Notes.

Has anyone done something like this or have any though as to how this could be accomplished.

Comment: Please provide code snippet, the problem is difficult to understand without your implementation .

Comment: This more of a question as if it can be done and the best way to proceed.

Comment: I would recommend to wait a bit instead of trying to build it - this is an enhancement that is planned for a future version of Acumatica.

Comment: Please stop adding irrelevant tags and leave the relevant ones.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, Can you explain what you will be doing in this enhancement so I can inform my customer to possible wait ? Also do you know what release it will be in ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi EricP, Thanks for the info. I will give it a try and let you know how I make out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed one of two ways:

First way is you could create a button in which it would fetch the associated customer's notes and display them.

The second way is that you could override the PXSelecting action for the page and make sure the Customer ID selector has commit changes set to true.

Either way you go, you will need to fetch the notes using the customer's NoteID field from the Note table. One method would be:

```
BAccount cust = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(Base);
Note custNote = PXSelect<Note, Where<Note.noteID, Equal<Required<BAccount.noteID>>>>.Select(Base, cust.NoteID);
```

This should get you the result you desire. You can then display it however you choose.

NOTE: Please let me know if there are any syntax errors and I will correct them ASAP.